# Perfect Lua_Script that select the element from drop down list and wait for the page to render content

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm using scrapy and Splash to crawl website. I want a perfect lua script that first click the drop down button and from there it must select the specific country name e.g (Morroco) from this site (https://lenovocareers.com/#search) and wait for a page to render the required contents(Jobs) for only that city(Morroco). my lua script I've tried so far is shown below but note that it not working at all.

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  local search_buttton = splash:select("div.header-search")
  search_buttton:mouse_click()
  assert(splash:wait(1.5))

  local drop_buttton = splash:select_all("#select2-job-filter-locations-container")[1]
  drop_buttton:mouse_click()
  assert(splash:wait(1.5))

  local choose_buttton = splash:select("#select2-job-filter-locations-result-h0vd-Morroco")
  choose_buttton:mouse_click()
  assert(splash:wait(1.5))

  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

Comment: Have you checked if you can get the data without Splash? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Yes I did...I know I can use API call to scrape it but for some reason and good practise I want to learn Splash too.